# Python / Boto3 / How can i get a tag list with pagination?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pagination, boto3

I'd like to get a rds and each tag list using boto3 without 100 limits.

This is the code for getting the list of rds and each tag.

```
client = boto3.client('rds')
instances = client.describe_db_instances()['DBInstances']

for i in instances:
    db_instance_name = i['DBInstanceIdentifier']
    arn = i['DBInstanceArn']
    tags = client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=arn)
    for item in tags['TagList']:
        if item['Key'] == 'Name':
            print(db_instance_name,item['Value'])
```

And this is the code for pagination.

```
def all_rds_instances(page_size=20):
    client = session.client('rds')
    marker = ""
    pool = []
    while True:
        for instance in pool:
            yield instance
        if marker is None:
            break
        result = client.describe_db_instances(MaxRecords=page_size, Marker=marker)
        marker = result.get("Marker")
        pool = result.get("DBInstances")
```

How can I combine these 2 codes ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. In title you mention to get it with pagination. But on text you say without 100 limits. We can't help you to combine codes, but we can give you a code that works if we understand what is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the for loop to iterate over your all_rds_instances generator.

Your script would look like:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

def all_rds_instances(page_size=20):
    marker = ''
    pool = []
    while True:
        for instance in pool:
            yield instance
        if marker is None:
            break
        result = client.describe_db_instances(MaxRecords=page_size, Marker=marker)
        marker = result.get('Marker')
        pool = result.get('DBInstances')


for i in all_rds_instances():
    db_instance_name = i['DBInstanceIdentifier']
    arn = i['DBInstanceArn']
    tags = client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=arn)
    for item in tags['TagList']:
        if item['Key'] == 'Name':
            print(db_instance_name, item['Value'])
```

When you use the `yield` keyword your function becomes a generator and it works the same way as any iterable in python.

There is some cool answer about how generator works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)